# Using javascript comparison operators with variables

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

I'm trying to make sense of a fellow developer's code that likes to use conditional operators to store variables. It's a very neat way but I'm not sure what `? and :` means in below scenario.

```
var empId = getCurrentUserId(); //getCurrentUserId function returns an id. 
var thisUserName = (empId == '' ? getCurrentUserName() : empId.toUpperCase()); //getCurrentUserName returns a user name.
```

Also is this a sufficient way to store variables oppose to an if statement? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: id is numeric? if true, why you write uppercase?

Comment: @AlessandroMarchisio Why should empId have to be numeric ?

Comment: It's uppercase because the characters are not always consistent. empId is numeric, that's just how we roll!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`... ? ... : ...` is a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). It exists in [a lot of languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:). It's used like that:

```
variable = test ? assignIfTrue : assignIfFalse;
```

In your case, `thisUserName` will be assigned with `getCurrentUserName()` if `empId` is empty, and with `empId.ToUpperCase()` if not.

Comment: Cool thanks for the quick reply! That makes perfect sense. Can we add multiple conditions like - 
`(conditions) ? assignIfTrue : assignIfFalse;`

Comment: Yes. `(x == y && (z != t || z == v)) ? true : false` is right. Take care to put paretheses as ternary operator has usually a low precedence over other operators.

Comment: Gotcha! This very helpful.